# How to check if an element is visible with WebDriver - eternal loading

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

I'm testing a button that close a window. Then when I clicking in the button I need check If the Window closed.

I created this method:

```
enter code here




public boolean isElementPresent(String locatorKey) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(locatorKey));
        return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        Assert.assertFalse((isElementPresent(String.valueOf(By.xpath(locatorKey)))));
        return false;
    }
}





enter code here
```

But it`s not working. Selenium stays loading the last step for a long time and in the end shows this error

Command: [8139ce6f8c35642a752d7fbedb186ec6, findElement {using=xpath, value=By.xpath: By.xpath: By.xpath: By.xpath: By.xpath: By.xpath: By.xpath: By.xpath: By.xpath: By.xpath:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void isElementPresent(By Xpath) {
    
    boolean isPresente;

    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-component-name,'cardboard')]"));
        driver.findElement(Xpath);
        System.out.println("Elemento está na tela");

        isPresente = true;

    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        
        System.out.println("Elemento não está na tela");
        isPresente = false;
    }

    Assert.assertFalse(isPresente);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider use Selenide if you using Java.

```
$x("your xpath").should(disappear);
```

That's all you need to do with Selenide.

https://selenide.org/

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand